# express-openid-connect with multiple pm2 instances

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, pm2, express-openid-connect

I have a node js application that I use pm2 to start.  As part of my pm2 setup I use multiple instances of my app with the builtin pm2 features.  I currently moved from 1 instance to an instance per core, leaving me with 4 instances running.  As part of this app, I also use SSO authentication using express-openid-connect.  Before switching to multiple instances my SSO implementation worked correctly.  Recently we noticed SSO was not working as expected.  After some testing, I discovered and figured that the multiple instances were the root cause.  Since there are several calls between the backend and frontend needed for authentication, it seems the flow is hitting different instances within the same authentication request.  This causes it to lose state/cookie information.

Does anyone have an experience working with express-openid-connect and multiple instances of a node application?  My original thought was limiting the calls related to SSO to one instance by number, however, I don't have control of what instance is hit when making an SSO request.

Thank you!